# Command works only once every reload

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I just learned to use schedules and I wanted to make a repeating task but when I was done I noticed that the command only worked once every reload I did. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
public class SpawnCommand implements CommandExecutor {

public int i = 5;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    Player p = (Player) sender;
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spawn")) {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(JavaPlugin.getProvidingPlugin(Teams.class), new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        if (i != -1) {
                            if (i != 0) {
                                p.sendMessage("§8§l┃ §3Revenant §8┃  §eTeleporting in §c(" + i + "§c)");
                                 p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 1, 0 + i);
                                i--;
                            } else {
                                p.sendMessage("§8§l┃ §3Revenant §8┃  §eTeleporting...");
                                Location centerblock = new Location(p.getWorld(),
                                        p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation().getX() + 0.5,
                                        p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation().getY(),
                                        p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation().getZ() + 0.5);
                                p.teleport(centerblock);
                                p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.CAT_MEOW, 1, 0 );
                                p.playEffect(p.getPlayer().getLocation(centerblock), Effect.ENDER_SIGNAL, 1);
                                p.playEffect(p.getPlayer().getLocation(centerblock), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 1);
                                i--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 0L, 20L);
    }
    return true;
}
 }
```

Comment: Refer to [our documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bukkit/5436/scheduler-programming#t=201611171536580915453) to best understand Bukkit Task Scheduling. Your task shouldn't be async, as it uses the Bukkit API.

Answer (score 2):

The `i` within your task is shared between all tasks since it's declared in your command class.

Also, **your task needs to be sync**.  Using the Bukkit API asynchronously is not valid and *will* cause issues (though not the issues you were experiencing).

Here's a fixed version, using `BukkitRunnable` instead of `Runnable` as well so that the task can be canceled when it's no longer needed (right now, even when `i` is -1, the task still runs each tick, meaning that if the command were used a hundred times you'd have a hundred tasks each tick... not ideal).  `BukkitRunnable` makes it convenient to both start and cancel tasks.

```java
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;
// ... other imports ...

public class SpawnCommand implements CommandExecutor {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("§cYou must be a player to run use command.");
            return true;
        }
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spawn")) {
            BukkitRunnable task = new BukkitRunnable() {
                    /**
                     * Counter until teleport time
                     */
                    int i = 5;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (i != 0) {
                            p.sendMessage("§8§l┃ §3Revenant §8┃  §eTeleporting in §c(" + i + "§c)");
                            p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 1, 0 + i);
                            i--;
                        } else {
                            p.sendMessage("§8§l┃ §3Revenant §8┃  §eTeleporting...");
                            Location centerblock = new Location(p.getWorld(),
                                    p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation().getX() + 0.5,
                                    p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation().getY(),
                                    p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation().getZ() + 0.5);
                            p.teleport(centerblock);
                            p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.CAT_MEOW, 1, 0 );
                            p.playEffect(p.getPlayer().getLocation(centerblock), Effect.ENDER_SIGNAL, 1);
                            p.playEffect(p.getPlayer().getLocation(centerblock), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 1);

                            // This task is done; we can terminate it now
                            this.cancel();
                        }
                    }
            });
            task.runTaskTimer(JavaPlugin.getProvidingPlugin(Teams.class), 0L, 20L);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Since `new BukkitRunnable() {}` is actually creating a new class that extends `BukkitRunnable` inline, you can add member variables there.